# Allowing LAN-LAN Cascaded Router to Access Internet

Tags: networking, router, lan, wan

Below diagram is the set up which I am currently trying but doesn't work. My goal here is:

1. Both TV Box and PC are under the same subnet 192.168.1.0/24
2. Since Router 2 is a SIP client which connected to a desktop phone, it will need access to Internet.
3. I need my VPN server working so that I can connect to my home using VPN from my PC or smartphone.
4. I could add a switch and make Router 2 a SIP-to-RJ11 convertor only to solve this, but I don't want to do that unless I have no other choice.

[image: Routers setup]

Now my problem is: Everything is working now, except the desktop phone doesn't work.

Some information and limitation:

1. Router 1 is Synology rt1900ac.
2. Router 2 is a router provided from service provider. I only have access to some of the settings, but it is possible to request the service provider to change the other settings for us.
3. Router 2 WAN port is configured to connect using DHCP. The service provider claimed that there is no "bridge" connection on WAN port.
4. DHCP server on Router 2 is disabled.
5. There is a wall between Router 1 and Router 2.
6. I can see from Router 1 that Router 2 WAN port seems assigned to 192.168.1.2 using static DHCP from Router 1 but I have no way to verify it, because echo reply seems blocked on Router 2 WAN port.
7. I have requested to disable NAT on Router 2, and seems it is disabled right now because I cannot ping to Internet when I set the PC to 172.16.1.11.
8. Port forwarding for SIP (TCP/UDP 5060) has been configured on Router 1 to 192.168.1.2.
9. Desktop phone is working fine, if I connect Router 1 LAN port to Router 2 WAN port.

So my question is, what options I have in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: Unless your ISP-provided router has some sort of status log/display to show why the phone isn’t working, you can only guess. Keep in mind that SIP doesn’t play very nice with NAT. Your upstream router is most likely misconfigured somehow.

Comment: I just added more info to the question, actually the phone is working fine if I connect Router 1 LAN port to Router 2 WAN port. So I guess the problem is not related to SIP.

Comment: You have setup router2 to have two networks. Given that state, the RJ11 will surely prefer the one that goes through the WAN port. The RJ11 is not just another LAN port. As you don't have networked computers on the router1 side of the wall, you can stay with that configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I could't found a solution and ended up using the following setup. That is, using the Router 2 for solely for phone purpose. Thanks everyone for giving suggestion so far.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have setup router2 to have two networks, but the RJ11 will try to use
the one that goes through the WAN port.
The RJ11 is after all not just another LAN port.

As you don't have networked computers on the router1 side of the wall, you can stay with the configuration where Router 1 LAN port is connected to
Router 2 WAN port, thus creating its own network segment.

If the reason for your particular setup is that you are trying to isolate
one computer from the others, you can achieve that by using
[VLANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN),
if supported by router2, or add a third router
(which will not help the performance of the isolated computer).

Comment: If Router 1 LAN port is connected to Router 2 WAN port, how can I achieve my goal 2 "Both TV Box and PC are under the same subnet 192.168.1.0/24"? Regarding isolation, no, I don't really need to have isolation here.

Comment: A physical solution is to draw a cable back through the wall to the TV, or use power line adapters. A software solution is to add routes to the computer to the other network so it can access the TV.

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand your software solution. Would you mind edit your answer and explain in more details with IP addresses, actual route configuration, LAN configuration of Router 2, etc, that will be used? Physical solution is what I tried to avoid.